# How to transform & duplicate an array (or dimension of array) so that each element is in a different index each time

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, data-transform

(in c#)

I have a huge chunk of game data that I have broken down using a multidimensional array. It is shaped thus:

string [,,,] data = new string[18,18,19,2]

however, ultimately, that last dimension should be larger. in the last dimensionality, index 0 will stay the same, and values from index 1 will be copied into index 2 and 3, but with different indexes in the next dimension up, with no repeats.

So index 0,0,0,1 can have the same value as 0,0,1,2 but not 0,0,0,2. By extension, **neither** 0,0,0,1 nor 0,0,0,2 can equal 0,0,0,3 but 0,0,1,3 is fine.

I need duplicate the data with 1 to 1 re-assignment, and sufficiently pseudo-random for no pattern to be apparent to the user. Performance is somewhat a consideration (transformation does not re-occur often).

I'm at a loss. I've been googling for 2 hours, and also tried to figure it out myself. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

found this:

```
function mapOrder (array, order, key) {

  array.sort( function (a, b) {
    var A = a[key], B = b[key];

    if (order.indexOf(A) > order.indexOf(B)) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return -1;
    }

  });

  return array;
};
```

Seems Like I can just pre-make a 2d array of pairs of prebuilt transforms the exact length I need, which follow these rules when matched with each other and with the original. A bit of a cheat, but very cost effective. If performance is an issue, I can always linearize my arrays into 1d, but I would do that after building it out for my own sanity.